# How to make UPPAAL use the strategy I wrote when doing verification?

Tags: uppaal

I'm a student now using UPPAAL for academic research.For some reasons, I want to write some strategies to optimize the process when UPPAAL verification.

I mean, if I have a search strategy specific to my current model that reduces the memory and time needed to formally verify that model, where or how can I implement it?

I know I can use verifyta.exe and choose the searching strategy,but how can I choose my strategy?

Furthermore, if I want to apply some algorithms or techniques to the process of reachable analysis, what should I do?

I have checked UPPAAL's official website and some other information, but I couldn't find any relevant solutions. Does UPPAAL not allow users to make such modifications?

Comment: How do you imagine such support? What shape or form? Can you give an example?
I am afraid, UPPAAL does not have it, but it supports sweep-line method, where one can define a `progress` measure then UPPAAL will explore the state space in sweeps.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.